# Checking the condition Before uploading in to the table

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

From the below executeUpdate() method i want to update the data in the db2 table. Before doing that i want to check whether C_Conf and D_Conf has values "Yes" means i need to replace with 'Y' and if value is "NO" means  I need to replace with 'N'. where Can i check this and append to update query.

In the executeUpdate() i just hardcoded the value as 'N' for C_Conf and D_Conf. here i want to check whether value is "Yes" means i need to replace as 'Y' or if it is "NO" means i need to replace with 'N'. How to check and where in the code? Please help

```
 public class DbTask {

Connection connection;

Statement statement, statement1; 

public boolean executeQuery(String dbQuery){

    boolean  result = false;

     connection = DatabaseConnection.getCon();

     try {

         statement = connection.createStatement();


                     result = statement.execute(dbQuery);

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

   return result;
}


public boolean cleanTable(String schema, String tableName) {

    boolean  result = false;

     connection = DatabaseConnection.getCon();

     try {

         statement = connection.createStatement();

        // can be implemented later for deleteing the table data

    } catch (SQLException e) {


        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   return result;

}
```

public void executeUpdate() {

```
  String selectQuery = "select 

                                                                                                                 S_NUMBER,CON,D_CON,R_CON,VAL_CON 

                      from

                      OTG.S_SAMPLE_VAL" 

                      +"  WHERE R_TS = (SELECT MAX(R_TS) FROM 

                       OTG.S_SAMPLE_VAL)";

  Statement statement;

try {
     connection = DatabaseConnection.getCon();

     statement = connection.createStatement();

     statement1 = connection.createStatement();

  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectQuery);

  while(rs.next()){

      StringBuffer updateQuery = new StringBuffer();

       updateQuery.append("update OTG.R_VAL set ");

       updateQuery.append("C_Conf='");

       updateQuery.append( "N', ");

      // updateQuery.append(rs.getString(2) + "', ");

       updateQuery.append("D_Conf='");

     //  updateQuery.append(rs.getString(3) + "', ");

                updateQuery.append( "N', ");

       updateQuery.append("REVE=");

       updateQuery.append(rs.getString(4) + ", ");

       updateQuery.append("VAL='");

       updateQuery.append(rs.getString(5) + "' ");

       updateQuery.append("where S_NO ='" + rs.getString(1) + "'");

       System.out.println(updateQuery.toString());

       statement1.executeUpdate(updateQuery.toString());

      }



} catch (SQLException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

          e.printStackTrace();

}
```

}

}

Comment: Learn prepared statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just update the values in a single query as opposed to finding the row first and then updating it.  There's not much point in making the database find and return the row, only to then update it in another (unnecessary) trip to the database:

```
update OTG.S_SAMPLE_VAL
   set  C_CONF = case C_CONF when 'Yes' then 'Y'
                             when 'No'  then 'N' 
                             else C_CONF end 
       ,D_CONF = case D_CONF when 'Yes' then 'Y'
                             when 'No'  then 'N' 
                             else D_CONF end    
 where R_TS = (SELECT MAX(R_TS) FROM OTG.S_SAMPLE_VAL)
   and C_CONF in ('Yes','No') or D_CONF in ('Yes','No');
```

Better yet, why not add a trigger to the database to update the row *before the insert happens*, or even better, update the application that is inserting the row to insert the desired value (`'Y'` or `'N'`) ?

Comment: Hi Lan, Thanks for the reply, I am Updating the data in Table R_VAL by select the distinct rows from the table S_SAMPLE_VAL with respective to the column S_NO. While updating data into table R_VAL i need to replace the column value buy "Y" if it is 'yes' or "N" if it is 'No' irrespective of the case(upper or lower) used.

Comment: I tried above query.. but it resulted in error as " Multiple columns are returned from a subquery that is allowed only one column.. SQLCODE=-412, SQLSTATE=42823, DRIVER=4.8.86" . I tried the below as u said.

Comment: update OTG.R_VAL set  C_CONF = case C_CONF when 'Yes' then 'Y'
when 'No'  then 'N' else C_CONF end ,D_CONF = case D_CONF when 'Yes' then 'Y' when 'No'  then 'N' else D_CONF end where S_NO = (SELECT S_NUM,CON,DIS,REV,VAL FROM OTG.S_R_VAL WHERE R_TS = (SELECT MAX(R_TS) FROM OTG.S_R_VAL)) and C_CONF in ('Yes','No') or C_CONF in ('Yes','No')